# Notepad++ Multi-Editing

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++, inline-editing

I’m new around here and i wanted to know if there is possible to make multi-editing still work after you press ***ENTER OR TAB***. It’s like this you go to line 5-6-7 and want to paste a line of code right after them by pressing enter and entering a new line or you want to move the lines 5-6-7 with tabs so they look nested to parent or in some other examples. (it runs perfectly in Sublime Text 2 )

I hope i was explicitly enough and straight to the point , sorry for misspelled words or bad english.

**[EDIT] :**

I wanted to add some pictures with the example but i need 10 reputation... I will try to explain once more . Notepad++ allows you to do multi-editing , it works perfectly to write inline continiously without pressing enter, if you press enter is going to  enter a new line at the last position where you wanted to modify with multi-editing .

I am going to write an in-line example here:

```
<div id="1">
  <div class="child-1"></div> <-[here is where i hold CTRL for multi editing]
</div>

<div id="2">
  <div class="child-1"></div> <-[here is where i hold CTRL for multi editing]
</div>
```

So i want in both of parent *divs* [id=1 & id=2] after the *div* with class="child-1" to enter a new line [by pressing **ENTER**] and write something else like a new *div* with class="child-2" , but simultaneously in both of the parents.

```
<div id="1">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div><-[this is how it should be ]
</div>

<div id="2">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div><-[this is how it should be ]
</div>


  [BUT UNFORTUNATELY IS GOING TO BE LIKE THIS ]

<div id="1">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div><-[this is how it is ]
</div>
```

This kind of thing happens too if you want to space more lines of code with **TAB** so they will  look nested to their parrents.

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. Perhaps give an example showing the text before and after the wanted changes are made. The English and spelling are OK but there is not enough information in the question.

Comment: @Philip D. If you dont click code snippet but instead click the Code sample button (`{}`) you will post code without run now buttons.

Answer (score 1):

**Tab** works for me with inline continuous editing by:

1. Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> Multi-Editing Settings -> (check) Enable
2. Single left-click the first location for insertion
3. Hold Control + single left-click the second location for insertion
4. Tab, or type something then tab. Auto-completion will interrupt multi-line editing, so disable it as necessary for this operation.

**Enter**, by itself, exited multi-line editing for me as well. However, you mentioned "pasting" multiple lines, which did work for me. So I recommend preparing what you want to insert on another tab/doc, copy that with a new line at the beginning, ie. shown with chars:

```
CRLF
<div class="child-2"></div>CRLF
```

Switch to your destination tab, repeat steps 1 thru 3 above, and CTRL + V to paste.

Tested in Notepad++ v6.6.7 Build Jun 24 2014

Comment: Thanks for the info alltough it still dosen't work fully as i tought , it works the same as it was and the example you told it's good if you disable auto-completion ... but it's not so reliable. I tought there might be a plug-in or something that does so , this thing with multi-editing and pressing **enter** or **tab** can be achive as i said in sublime text 2 but  finally you can work your thing without it. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question . Good luck !